# Play Framework : How to open video file in scala.html file?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am new in play framework I wanted to open video on click in new window. Please help me to write function in java.

First HTML
//After click is call following java action

```
<a target="_blank" id="linkTab@activity.id" href="/video/:@activity.file.path/open">@activity.file.name</a>
```

JAVA ACTION

```
public static Result openVideo(String filePath)
    {
        String videoPath = filePath.substring(1, filePath.length());
        return ok(views.html.activity.video.render(videoPath));
    }
```

RESULT HTML:
// @file is file name in my docs/folder

```
<embeded src="http://localhost:9000/docs/@file" height="240" width="320" autoplay="true">
```

it is redirecting and opening result html page but video not playing :(

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: <a target="_blank" id="linkTab@activity.id" href="/video/:@activity.file.path/open">@activity.file.name</a> : HTML